# Auth0 checkSession call to renew return an HTML error page

Tags: oauth-2.0, auth0

I have a Single Page App using Auth0 [Implicit Flow with Silent Authentication](https://auth0.com/docs/api-auth/tutorials/silent-authentication). I got the authentication part working just fine, but when I try to implement `checkSession` method to renew the session in the background (as per https://auth0.com/docs/libraries/auth0js/v9#using-checksession-to-acquire-new-tokens), the AJAX call to the auth0.com domain returns a 400 **HTML** error instead of a JSON one.

```js
webAuth.checkSession({}, function (err, authResult) {
  ...
});
```

The error is `Oops!, something went wrong`, which I can see in my browser devtools Network Response tab.

> There could be a misconfiguration in the system or a service outage. We track these errors automatically, but if the problem persists feel free to contact us.
>   Please try again.

I am not sure why there would be an HTML response, and not sure what I might be doing wrong. I have added my page's domain to the "Allowed Web Origins" list on the Auth0 application settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I was missing was providing the `redirectUri` parameter to the `checkSession` call.

I also found out that I could find logs to these errors by going to the "Logs" menu on the Auth0 dashboard.